# Scala import class in same folder

Tags: java, scala

I am a beginner in Scala coming from Java background.
I have two singleton object definition in two files as below.

LongLines.scala

```
import scala.io.Source

object LongLines {

  def processFile(filename: String, width: Int) {
    val source = Source.fromFile(filename)
    for (line <- source.getLines)
      processLine(filename, width, line)
  }

  private def processLine(filename: String,
      width: Int, line: String) {

    if (line.length > width)
      println(filename +": "+ line.trim)
  }
}
```

FindLongLines.scala

```
object FindLongLines {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val width = args(0).toInt
  for (arg <- args.drop(1))
    LongLines.processFile(arg, width)
}
```

}

I have first compiled LongLines.scala with the below command

```
[root@vm test_longlines]# scalac LongLines.scala 
[root@vm test_longlines]# ls
FindLongLines.scala  LongLines.class  LongLines$.class  LongLines.scala
```

Now, When I try to run with the below command I am getting cannot find symbol for 'LongLines'.

```
[root@vijayvm test_longlines]# scala -cp . FindLongLines.scala 10 LongLines.scala 
/home/scala/dev/test_longlines/FindLongLines.scala:5: error: not found: value LongLines
    LongLines.processFile(arg, width)
    ^
```

one error found

Should I gave to import LongLines in FindLongLines.scala ? Both are in the same folder but I have used package.

Comment: what you posted works for me. Are you using packages?

Comment: nope.no using packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st, you didn't compile `FindLongLines.scala` also?

2nd, in Scala you may have more than one object/class in a single File. Maybe it's overkill to separate so small objects in two files for a command line application

Comment: compiling FindLongLines.scala helped. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add the import line to the top

```
import package_name._
```

or

```
import package_name.longlines
```

Comment: i dont use package

Comment: I usully keep my codes and stuff in a folder package called src or something. Change 'package_name' to the name of your package